# Valid Palindrome, solution too slow for large input sizes

Tags: java, string, optimization, stringbuilder, palindrome

I am having an issue with a particular leetcode problem called *Valid Palindrome*. My code works for all test cases except the last test case 479/480.

In this test case a 106890 length string is passed in but my code takes too long to solve it.

I decided to try take a different approach and use the `StringBuilder` class to reverse the string and then simply use `reversedString.equals(originalString)` to compare whether they are a palindrome. **This approach solves the question and passes all testcases**

Why doesn't my two pointer approach work? Why does it fail on the last test case?

Here is my solution (Two Pointer)

```java
class Solution {
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String fixedString = "";
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isLetter(c)) {
                fixedString += c;
            }
        }
        fixedString = fixedString.toLowerCase();
        int i = 0;
        int j = fixedString.length() - 1;
        System.out.println(fixedString.toCharArray());
        while (i <= j) {
            if (fixedString.toCharArray()[i] != fixedString.toCharArray()[j]) {
                return false;
            }
            i += 1;
            j -= 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my second solution using `StringBuilder`.

```java
public class Valid_Palindrome {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String fixedString = "";
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isLetter(c)){
                fixedString += c;
            }
        }
        fixedString = fixedString.toLowerCase();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fixedString);
        sb = sb.reverse();
        System.out.println(sb);
        return sb.toString().equals(fixedString);
    }
}
```

Technically speaking, isn't the second solution supposed to be much slower since it is using `StringBuilder`?

How do I optimize my first solution?

Here is the input string that is passed in my leetcode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't build or reverse or do *anything* with the string, except iterate over half its characters.

In pseudo code:

- Loop over the first half of the characters
- For the ith character, compare it with the (length - i - 1)th character
- If different, return false
- If loop ends, return true

Answer (score 0):

It is generally slow to perform string concatenation in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder` instead in the first loop to create the filtered string.

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
        sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
}
for (int i = 0, j = sb.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    if (sb.charAt(i) != sb.charAt(j))
        return false;
return true;
```

Comment: I replaced my fixedString+= c with fixedString.append(c) it still times out, on the two pointer solution.

Comment: @KhandkarIslam See my solution in my answer.

Comment: @Unmitigated a nice solution, especially the second loop that will take only half the time of looping through the entire string. With a bit more effort you can also get rid of the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of statements in your code that are probably slowing it down.

1. `fixedString += c;`
   This creates a new `StringBuilder` object. The contents of `fixedString` are copied to it. Then the character (`c`) is appended. Then the `StringBuilder` is converted to a `String` and that `String` is assigned to variable `fixedString`.
2. `if (fixedString.toCharArray()[i] != fixedString.toCharArray()[j])`
   Method `toCharArray` creates a new `char[]` and copies the contents of the `String` to it.

I suggest that you create the `char[]` once only and work with it. Of-course you need to remove the non-letters and non-digits from the original string as well as convert to lower case.

Here is my rewrite of your [two pointer] solution.
(Note that I assume that a null or empty string is not a palindrome.)

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        char[] temp = new char[chars.length];
        int count = 0;
        for (char c : chars) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isLetter(c)) {
                temp[count++] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
        }
        char[] letters = new char[count];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, letters, 0, count);
        int i = 0;
        int j = count - 1;
        System.out.println(letters);
        while (i < j) {
            if (letters[i] != letters[j]) {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```